# Mapreduce in R - how can i implement "loop if" in reduce?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, mapreduce

This is my example dataset:

```
x <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3")
y <- c(5347, 5347, 5347, 1819, 1758, 1212, 1212, 1456)
```

I can't prepare this dataset like input from mapreduce's query after "map|sort", because I have separate **\t** and after this (it's necessary step in mapreduce to split rows):

```
fields <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\t"))
```

where ***line*** is my input I get two fields:

- fields[[1]] = **all column x**
- fields[[2]] = **all column y**

**I want to get this result:**

```
ID Count Unique number  
A1    1 (only 5347)
A2    3 (1819, 1758, 1212)
A3    1 (only 1456)
```

How can I count this, where loop observe column X and Y as long as will search new number in column X and count unique number in column Y for all unique number in column X??

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @Roger, we are in similar boat as agstudy, you need to post expected sample output for your question to make sense

Comment: @Roger I see right now you are new at SO. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to ask a question.

Comment: Maybe now is more clearer question?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear (Maybe because of an English problem). But from the expected result, I think you are looking for something like:

```
tapply(y,x,function(t)length(unique(t)))

A1 A2 A3 
 1  3  1
```

Which in English :

> Computing the number of unique y for each x.

Comment: I know this function, but it doesn't work in mapreduce...probably this should be "if loop"